# How to create folder, files in this folder, compress folder (in zip or rar file) and upload this to the desktop with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, directory, archive

For a web application, an user must be able to export an html file with css stylesheet of choice (proposed by the application) on his desktop.

A unique button for export : on click, a "Save as" dialog window appears for choose a destination on desktop. The file must have extension .zip (or .rar) and he contains html and css files.

How can I do this (without library) ? Thanks.

Comment: You need to do this using any server side language. This is not possible using javascript.

Comment: It's theoretically possible to do it entirely with client side JS, but its massively broad subject so not really suitable for a Stackoverflow question… and writing functions to create a zip or rar archive from scratch is madness. We use libraries for a reason.

Comment: @Quentin : Ok, do you know a light library for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JSZip library to do this
https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
var img = zip.folder("images");
img.file("smile.gif", imgData, {base64: true});
var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
saveAs(content, "example.zip");
```